# How to use Create react app to install React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

Hi I'm really new to react and I can't figure out how to actually install it or whatever it is I need to do to write code in it. I downloaded node.js and I have v12.18.3 installed as well as NPM 6.14.6 installed as well, but every time I try to type in the commands in the create-react-app installation method mentioned on many websites I get an error message saying: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`. Am I supposed to be typing directly into node? I have Visual code studio installed am I supposed to use that in some way? I see there’s a github repository for create-react-app, does this mean I have to download it to my pc to run it? Does React just have a CDN I can use to skip all this?

Comment: What is the command that you are typing?

Comment: Can you show the exact message with stack trace?

Comment: @Nootuff `npx create-react-app <appName>` is this what you ran?

Comment: Hi, thanks to everyone who answered, turns out I just had to run all the commands in the console rather than node. I think I have it working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[create-react-app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app)**   is the command to create the react app.
But it is not necessary to install it to create-react-app.

Best thing you have to do is,

```
npx create-react-app <app-name-here>
```

This makes install [create-react-app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app) install in the runtime of the command with using npx.

As an example,

```
npx create-react-app my_app
```

Try this.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Use following command and let's get start:

```
npx create-react-app <app-name>

Ex:

npx create-react-app demo-app
```