# I can't create a react app and I keep getting the same errors

Tags: reactjs

I run the command, but I get the errors with stuff I don't understand. node -v is v16.14.0

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Create react app to install React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63196431/how-to-use-create-react-app-to-install-react)

Comment: Please read [ask], in particular the part about not posting pictures of text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm start does not work for ract template project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54226082/npm-start-does-not-work-for-ract-template-project)

Answer (score -1):

It's problem in,  you're `npm version` consider using a stable version of npm [npm version](https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm)

> run this command `npm install -g npm@latest` it will install the new version of npm
> if it's still not working use flag while creating react app `npx create-react-app newapp -force` and `npm cache clear --force`

> In case it still not working delete `package-lock.json` from you're project and run `npm install` again

Comment: Didn't  work. :(

Comment: check i updated answer

Comment: I still can't create an app

Comment: restart you're computer and try again

Comment: check now answer has been updated

Answer (score -2):

Try to avoid Node latest version 17.0. Use 14 or 16 version instaed.