# How can i use ReactDOM and react imports

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I'm not using CDN links. I'm using imports instead so I don't know if it really works without CDN links.
here is my app.js file it's so simple but it's not
working.

```
import React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const root = document.getElementById('root');



ReactDOM.render(<h1>React</h1>, root);
```

Comment: how did you create React project? can you please share some more info

Comment: [Here is link how to create react project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63204478/6299168)
if you something looking for this

Comment: I'm react beginner so I'm just testing some basic stuff in js file and very simple HTML file

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing

```
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

To:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
```